# Microsoft.Practices.Unity does not exist in namespace Microsoft.Practices

Tags: c#, silverlight

Quick question folks.  Where is Unity now located?  My code is complaining that it's not in Microsoft.Practices.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Microsoft.Practices.Unity package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674014/where-is-microsoft-practices-unity-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll

You can also get it as part of the [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) download.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll is a separate assembly in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin directory. (EL V5.0)

Comment: Silverlight cannot link with standard .Net libraries. It has to be a Silverlight specific version of Unity.