# Where is Microsoft.Practices.Unity package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, unity-container

An hour ago I updated my nuget packages for the solution I'm working on and I get the error message, thrown by Unity, that

> The type 'IUnityContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.

Since then I have been googling to get some usable information about that where this package is. The articles, question around it are old, deals with 2.x version.

There is no such package in Nuget.

I have the packages listed below from Unity stack installed:

```
  <package id="Unity" version="4.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Unity.ServiceLocator" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Unity.WebAPI" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/4.0.1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After adding the nuget with

```
Install-Package Unity
```

it is located in

```
packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
```

You probably just need to add a reference to this assembly.

Comment: I installed a wrong package, 4.0.2 published by AgileSight. The 4.0.1 - which references automatically the Miicrosoft.Practices.Unity.dll - was published by Microsoft and working like a charm.

Comment: Make sure you don't install the newest package but exactly the Version 4.0.1. Then it works great!

Answer (score 36):

I had to change

```
using Microsoft.Practices.unity;
```

to

```
using Unity;
```

I think because of an update in Unity with NuGet

Comment: Thanks; you saved me a couple of hours

Comment: IN my case i am only installing the Unity.WebAPI Nuget. But its failing.Its searching for the Using UNity; although i have installed it i can't see it

Comment: @lokanathdas i am facing the same problem. I have installed unity 5.11.4 but it gives me error when i am trying to resolve class (container.Resolve<HomeVM>()) . 

Error = CS0308 The non-generic method 'IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type, string, params ResolverOverride[])' cannot be used with type arguments

Answer (score 0):

Update Unity with Nuget. I use NuGet Package Manager instead of command line. Access Manager by right-clicking the solution in the Solution Explorer from Visual Studion