# namespace name 'Practices' does not exist

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces

I have added recent enterprise library using nuget package manager but still getting below error while deploying (not while building).

Package manager: Install-Package EnterpriseLibrary.Data

Can anyone help me

The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: On the machine you are deploying on. Are you shure the NuGet package is being downloaded

Comment: thank you guys, its was issue related to TFS/local reference issue, created seperate folder in TFS director for references and placed dll files and refered from there, Fixed issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that your project is referencing to

- *Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common*
- *Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data*

[image]

Comment: Googling brought me here. I found my answer here without having to install the above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47621038/2850898